# Number of $5$-digit sequences with at least two $4$s.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to figure out how many five-digit sequences (0-9)  have at least two fours in them. ex: 41234 or 44086 .....
Here's my understanding:

Total number of possible sequences as $10^5 = 100000$

Total number of sequences without any 4: $9^5 = 59049$.

Total number of sequences with only one 4:  $9^4 = 6561$.

Total number of sequences with at least two fours is : $100000 - (59049+6561)$
Is this correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost. For the sequences with only one 4, there are five positions that 4 could lie in. So it's 6561 * 5. And the rest is correct.

Comment: @TonyMathew Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Well noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the total number of five-digit sequence is $10^5$ and that there are $9^5$ sequences with no $4$s.  As Tony Mathew pointed out in the comments, the number of sequences with exactly one $4$ is $5 \cdot 9^4$ since there are five ways to place the $4$ and $9$ choices for each of the remaining four positions.  Hence, the number of five-digit sequences with at least two $4$s is
$$10^5 - 9^5 - 5 \cdot 9^4$$